# toString if condition is true add something

Tags: c#, .net

Well I have this ToString method:

```
public override string ToString() => $"{id} {Lastname} {Firstname} [{IsMale} {done}]";
```

And if Done is not null between IsMale and Done should be a `,` but if the Done is null there should be nothing

Comment: {(done != null ? ", " + done : "")}

Comment: May you please implement it for me into the ToString(). I am copletely lost at the moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public override string ToString() => $"{id} {Lastname} {Firstname} [{IsMale} {(done != null ? ", " + done : "")}]";
```